# How do i solve this SISS thing?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl

> TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> ---
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [Union All [303]]: The metadata for "Union 
>     All.Inputs[Union All Input 3].Columns[Title]" does not match the metadata for 
>     the associated output column.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [Union All [303]]: Failed to set property 
>     "OutputColumnLineageID" on "Union All.Inputs[Union All Input 
>     3].Columns[Title]".
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0204006 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
>
> ---
>
> BUTTONS:
>
> OK
>
> ---

I keep getting this error when i try to do data conversion and then try to do union... This is because, if you know, the data conversion, will create new columns. SO when i try to do union with them, it will get the bove error.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to delete and re-add those connections between sources and union.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once and what I did was as follows:

1)Double click the respected data-conversion which faulty data is passing through
2)Check to see if all the data types for you columns are matching with the data type of same column from your other data-conversion.
3)Fix if there is any difference

And this will fix it for you, as it did for me.

Comment: "Fix if there is any difference". The hard thing is to know _how_ to fix it. You cannot change the output data type directly. You have to change it indirectly by either a) temporarily changing one of the respective input columns to a different input column and then back again to the original column, or b) completely delete the problematic mapping and re-add it. Afterwards, the output data type will be in sync with the input data types again.

Answer (score 0):

Double click the  UNION ALL component to display the output Column Names.

Change Union All Input 1 and the Union All Input 2 to

Rename you column  and add a new column with the right name  and the right data.
Now you have the right column with the right types,you can delete your old renamed column.

Don't forget to update the derived column and destination compnenent. The will be updated automatically with the unwanted renamed column. Just configure the right column in these component and refresh. all will be right.